# How do I edit files with Web IDE in Bluemix DevOps?

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, node-red, web-ide

My ultimate goal is to simply edit the package.json file to add the momentjs library so I can access it my node red app running in bluemix, but my question is even more fundamental.

My setup:
I have a bluemix nodejs app running a simple node red app I created. I want to use the moment.js library to do some date math and understand I need to update the dependencies file in the package.json file.

Question:
When I go to my Bluemix console runtime screen for node.js I can see the package.json file and can click on it to see the contents, but can't edit. I have tried creating projects/Git and can't see this file. I can use CLI using CF and get to the file and view it but again I just don't know how to edit it.

I would really like to understand how I can see these files and edit/source code control them using the Web IDE and just can't figure it out. I do fundamentally understand source code control just don't understand how to set this all so I can specifically see this file.

Main goal is simply to update the package.json file in the app directory.

Answer (score 0):

In your Bluemix Dashboard,click on your APP and in the APP Overview you will see ADD GIT BUTTON(top right corner).

Click on it and once you've added your project to GIT, you will get a GIT URL.

Go to that URL and click on EDIT CODE( you can update your package.json) and then commit the changes.

Comment: That's the puzzling part for me. I have done that a number of times also including the starter package or not. When I don't select to load the starter package, I don't even get a package.json. When I choose the starter package before launching GIT, I get the package.json just not this one and I don't even seem to see this app directory at all. I have an existing node red app and it doesn't seem to see any of this. All the documentation about using Web IDE and GIT indicates you can 1. start new, 2. bring an app in, or 3. use your existing one. The only describe how to do the first two.